# create a clickable link in MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I'm in the process of learning some coding. I am looking to create the results of MySQL results clickable. I would like the name (first and last name) to be "clickable" so they can link to the customer record to view. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<table class="list"; > 
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>

    <?php while($customers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customer_set)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo h($customers['first_name'].' '.$customers['last_name']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo h($customers['address1']. ' '.$customers['city'].', '.$customers['state'].' '.$customers['zip']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo h($customers['email1']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo h($customers['phone1']); ?></td>

        </tr>

    <?php } ?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want clickable first name and last name then you need to add anchor tag with view url like below examples.

**Example (send first name and last name separately)**

```
<td><a href="view-record.php?fname=<?php echo h($customers['first_name'] ?>&lname=<?php echo h($customers['last_name'] ?>"><?php echo h($customers['first_name'].' '.$customers['last_name']); ?></a></td>
```

Better solution is you can send id of user . For example i am asuming you have one column `id` in customers table then you can pass id like below example

```
<td><a href="view-record.php?uid=<?php echo $customers['id']; ?>"><?php echo h($customers['first_name'].' '.$customers['last_name']); ?></a></td>
```

**Note: You can encrypt id by using some hash methods to securely pass id of user.**

Now when you click on these links you will redirect on view page where you can get these id or firstname, lastname by using GET method.

**Example**

**view-record.php**

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['uid'])) {
     $userid = $_GET['uid']; //please add some validation before using this value.
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `<a>` (anchor) html tag like this:

```
<table class="list"; > 
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>

    <?php while($customers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customer_set)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="http://example.com/customer/id/<?php echo $customers['id']; ?>"><?php echo h($customers['first_name'].' '.$customers['last_name']); ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo h($customers['address1']. ' '.$customers['city'].', '.$customers['state'].' '.$customers['zip']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo h($customers['email1']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo h($customers['phone1']); ?></td>

        </tr>

    <?php } ?>
```

Replace the url `http://example.com/...` with whatever real url you want to use for the link.